# How to use a place picker after google places api got deprecated

Tags: android, maps, google-places-api

Earlier when I have used google places API, I was able to hover over the map using a pin and dropping it on a certain point would help me retrieve the location. It was very simple.
 Like how a customer would select his food delivery location or cab pickup point.

But after the recent changes to the API, I am not able to find the map fragment that came along when implementing the places API.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro

I am aware of the custom and compatibility library. Still couldn't figure out how to include a map fragment in the places API.

Am I missing something or is that how it is going to be hereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have migrated to the new SDK, you will not be able to use the Place Picker as this can only be used using the old SDK, if you are now using Places API instead of Places SDK for Android, then you will not be able to use the Place Picker any more as it  is now [deprecated as of January 29, 2019](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker). Since you are expressing the interest for Place Picker after it has been deprecated, kindly fill up the [form in this issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/128304760). Thank you.